# Is there a method to get all the LiveDoc Documents of a project in Polarion

Tags: polarion

Is there a method to get all the LiveDoc Documents of a project
I want to use this in Scheduler script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Luckily there is a nice function in the API which is never exposed to the Polarion UI (would really like to hear the story about this).

This is a velocity script getting all Documents (They are called "Modules" in the API) in a single project:

```
#foreach($doc in $trackerService.dataService.searchInstances($trackerService.dataService.getPrototype("Module"), "project.id:$page.project", "space,id"))
* $doc.id
#end
```

The API call `searchInstances()` can find you anything: User, Workitems, Testruns, Documents ,etc.

Comment: Thank you @peter this is exactly what I am looking for
I really appreciate your help

Comment: If this solves your Problem, you should mark this as the correct answer, so other people can use this answer as well. Otherwise this question stays as unanswered.

Comment: hi @AnasHosami could you demonstrate how to use it a bit further?